# Choosing filter capacitor and inductor for AC to DC rectifier

Tags: capacitor, motor-controller, bridge-rectifier, ripple

I am designing a three phase AC to DC rectifier. This DC output will be connected to a 6 IGBT bridge. That IGBT will be controlled using SVPWM technique to control a PMSM motor. What factors do I need to design this rectifier. I need to determine the inductance and capacitance values. The number of capacitors to be used and so forth. For reference I give below the parameters of my design.

- Three Phase AC supply: 220 V, 50- Hz
- PMSM Motor: 400 W, 2.4 A, 108 V. HG-KR43 Mitsubishi
- Motor Inductance and resistance: Don't know. How to find out for my case?
- SVPWM Switching Frequency: 10 kHz
- Allowable Voltage Ripple: Don't know. How to find out for my case?
- Current Ripple: Don't know. How to find out for my case?

If there is a book that can explain all or any of these phenomenon that would be great. Papers and videos on youtube dont real give in depth knowledge of these things. I would be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: If you don't have any requirements to work against, you need to determine them. Is additional motor heating from ripple a concern? Inductance and resistance should be given in the datasheet for the motor or you can ask the manufacutrer.